# How change only url without rebuild in navigator 2.0

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I was trying to  change url using `Navigator 2.0`

As far as I can understand, Routing System call `RouteInformationParser.restoreRouteInformation` to update url when `RouterDelegate's notifyListener` method called

My problem is to rebuild all  `Widget` when `RouterDelegate's notifyListener` called

For example, I have changed part of the screen and would like to apply related information to the URL. At this time, there is no need to rebuild the screen.
If you change the current configuration value of `RouterDelegate` and call the `notifyListener` function, it rebuild the screen and change the URL.

Is there a way to change the URL only?

Comment: I am also trying to achieve the same. Have you found any solution for this?